# how to remove event listener on onclick of checkbox and it should be selectd bydefault true always

Tags: javascript

```
<div class="add-gift-message no-display" id="add-gift-options-86">
    <h3>Do you have any gift items in your order?</h3>
    <p>
        <input type="checkbox" name="allow_gift_options" id="allow_gift_options" value="1" onclick="toogleVisibilityOnObjects(this, ['allow-gift-options-container']);" class="checkbox" />
        <label for="allow_gift_options">Add gift options</label>
    </p>
</div>
<div class="gift-message-form" id="allow-gift-options-container">

<div class="inner-box">
        <div id="add-gift-options-for-order-86" class="no-display">
        <h4>Gift Options for the Entire Order</h4>
        <p>
            <input type="checkbox" name="allow_gift_messages_for_order" id="allow_gift_options_for_order" value="1" onclick="toogleVisibilityOnObjects(this, ['allow-gift-options-for-order-container']);" class="checkbox" />
            <label for="allow_gift_options_for_order">Add gift options for the Entire Order</label>
        </p>
    </div>
```

how to remove event listener on onclick of checkbox with id="add-gift-options-86" and without selecting checkbox should be selected depending on this other checkbox with id ="allow_gift_options_for_order" is also visible that should be selected by default

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Could you try to rephrase it (sentences and punctuation help)? It will be very hard for us to help you if we can't understand the question. :)

Comment: i have one checkBox onclick of that other checkBox get visible and onclick of that other hyperlink get visibles,but i want bydefault that both the checkbox should get checked and due to that hyperlink get visible ,how to do that please help thanks in advance